# Google apps - Trigger script when responseStatus change

Tags: events, google-apps-script, triggers, calendar, status

I would like to run a script each time the responStatus of an event is modified by an attendee.
By default when an attendee receive an invitation by email the status is "needsAction". And wether he accepts, decline, the responseStatus change to "accepted" or "declined".

I want to create a script which send a custom email, and trigger each time the status is changed by the attendees.

Anyone ?

Comment: show us your research and attempts. only way is to make a recurring trigger and keep comparing event data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple [tutorial on sending emails from a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails).  Note that you will need to add a column to denote that the email was sent as it will go through every row and send the spreadsheet.

I prefer [this example as a more complete one which does a mail merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) as well, allowing you to have a template message and replacing it with values from the row.

Go through this and as you have more specific questions, start a new thread.